# Is the reasoned verdict or sentencing remarks of Andrew Miller available to read?

Tags: criminal-law, scotland

Scotland cross dresser Andrew Miller has just been sentenced to 20 years imprisonment for abducting and abusing a young girl. What judicial materials are available from his case and where can they be read?

Comment: Search the web for "Andrew Miller" sentencing remarks.

Comment: @Lag and what about the reasoned verdict?

Comment: Scotland doesn't have "reasoned verdicts".

Comment: I’ve rolled back an edit on this question for which the rationale was not declared and which I didn’t feel improved my question.

Comment: Why is it necessary to include they are a cross dresser? Seems like a totally superfluous piece of information designed to push whatever agenda you have

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A judge may decide to publish a statement after passing sentence on an offender in cases where there is particular public interest; where a case has legal significance; or where providing the reasons for the decision might assist public understanding.

Lord Arthurson’s remarks on the sentence of Andrew George Miller on 18 October 2023 have been [published accordingly](https://www.judiciary.scot/home/sentences-judgments/sentences-and-opinions/2023/10/18/hma-v-andrew-miller).

Comment: What about the reasoned verdict?

Comment: @Seekinganswers the’ye in the sentencing statement “you tendered pleas of guilty”.